# About output of java code on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

i have following java code.
when i run this code the out-put is not desired. it produce transparent background.

```
package javagame2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.setBackground;


public class JavaGame2 extends JFrame {

    public JavaGame2(){
        setTitle("My Game");
        setSize(250,250);
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

   public void paint(Graphics g){
       g.drawString("Hello World", 75, 75);
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaGame2();
    }

}
```

when i add keylistener functions to my program then also no action is taken
i am using netbeans 8.0.2 and the Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 0):

Call super.paint() from your method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawString("Hello World", 75, 75);
   }
```